# Generate ireport in java using oracle 10g

Tags: java, oracle10g, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using ireport 4.5.0. In ireport generate success report but when I'm generating using java code through then it will gives the error.

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No query executer factory class registered for plsql queries.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.queryLanguageChanged(JRDesignDataset.java:1017)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.setQuery(JRDesignDataset.java:551)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign.setQuery(JasperDesign.java:896)
```

Comment: Can you post the java code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default support for PL/SQL. I think you're indicating that you have it working correctly in iReport. So you must have added a query executer for PL/SQL. You need to make that same query executer available in your JR runtime environment.